# Return array with the longest strings only

Tags: ruby

I need to have true in all 3 tests. I need to iterate the code until the array returns only the longest ones only.

```
# Tests
p longest(['tres', 'pez', 'alerta', 'cuatro', 'tesla', 'tropas', 'siete']) == ["alerta", "cuatro", "tropas"]
p longest(['gato', 'perro', 'elefante', 'jirafa']) == ["elefante"]
p longest(['verde', 'rojo', 'negro', 'morado']) == ["morado"]
```

Comment: You won't learn if we write here the solution for you. Please show the code you wrote that didn't work, and we'll help you to get it working.

Comment: Jusus, @spickermann has given a good answer, but in future consider waiting longer before awarding the greenie. Quick selections sort-circuit others still working on answers and may discourage other--sometimes better, sometimes just interesting--answers. There's no rush. Many here wait at least a couple of hours before making a selection.

Comment: Okay thanks Cary.  I'm new to stackoverflow, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, let's break it down...

First: find out how long the longest word is:

```
words = ['tres', 'pez', 'alerta', 'cuatro', 'tesla', 'tropas', 'siete']
words.map(&:length).max
#=> 6
```

Second select all words with that length:

```
words.select { |w| w.length == 6 }
#=> ["alerta", "cuatro", "tropas"]
```

Combine that to a method:

```
def longest(words)
  max_length = words.map(&:length).max
  words.select { |w| w.length == max_length }
end
```